# for(NSString *key in [rewards allKeys]) crashes the application?

Tags: iphone, ios

I have an application which is having a dictionary returned from a webservice.and i am passing that dictionary to another view controller.

and in this

```
NSDictionary *rewards=[rewardsdictionary objectForKey:@"rewards"];
NSLog(@"%@",rewards);

NSMutableArray *dataArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for(NSString *key in [rewards allKeys])
{
    NSDictionary *dict1=[rewards objectForKey:key];
    [dataArray addObject:dict1];
}
self.rewardsarray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
self.rewardsarray=dataArray;
```

But in this line `for(NSString *key in [rewards allKeys])` the application is crashing.but when i am printing rewards or rewards dictionary the values are there.

> -[__NSArrayM allKeys]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x76636b0

can anybody help me to get out of this?

Comment: what does <NSLog(@"%@",rewards);> log you out? post the log please...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Obviously, `rewards` is not a `NSDictionary`. It's an `NSArray`.

Answer (score 0):

Use NSAssert to check if `rewards` is an `NSDictionary` before sending `allKeys` message to it.

Comment: this will make the app to fail only a little earlier.

Comment: did you check and it was NSDictionary?